# google maps error. java.lang.RuntimeException error in the logcat

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement google maps in my app. but my app is unable to open with the message "unfortunately xxx has stopped".

I think it is the problem with the java.lang.RuntimeException. The main activity is unable to start.

**Logcat**

```
08-14 11:09:36.035: D/dalvikvm(989): GC_CONCURRENT freed 140K, 9% free 2664K/2920K, paused 20ms+25ms, total 88ms
        08-14 11:09:36.035: W/CursorWrapperInner(989): Cursor finalized without prior close()
        08-14 11:09:36.045: W/CursorWrapperInner(989): Cursor finalized without prior close()
        08-14 11:09:36.125: D/AndroidRuntime(989): Shutting down VM
        08-14 11:09:36.125: W/dalvikvm(989): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.Mapview
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.Mapview
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  ... 11 more
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.maps.Mapview" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.helloworld-1.apk
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        08-14 11:09:36.165: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  ... 21 more
        08-14 11:09:49.876: I/Process(989): Sending signal. PID: 989 SIG: 9
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" >

    <!-- <fragment  
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  /> -->

    <com.google.android.maps.Mapview
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:apiKey="AIzaSyDKbr_jYLBZ49jZeC78Zn64Rp9D2AiMs_4" 
         android:id="@+id/mvMain"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code and XML plus have your installed Google Play Services?

Comment: You should be using Fragment....!!

Comment: Dont use mapview.It is deprecated.Use GoogleMap V2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your manifest.xml file? To use the MapView you need to set a handfull of permissions on true and add some meta data.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_api_key"/>
<permission
        android:name="your.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="your.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your key" />
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_google_play_services_version_to_your_apps_manifest) is more info on the google site.